# React with Redux: Passing function to child component, calling without handler in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mqtt

I'm having trouble sending an action through a callback with the provided code below. The code does not send an action. However, I know if I attach the property Connected to a handler such as onClick, it will then execute. How can I get my code to work without one of these handlers?

(Note: In this example I'm using the MQTT.js library from npm).

Each time a connection message is received over the socket with MQTT, I want it to update the store to tell the front end when successfully connected. However, I need to keep the component a component, not a container.

Parent:

```
return (
  <MQTT
    Connected={() => {this.props.sendAction('MQTT_CONNECTED')}}
  >
)
```

Child:

```
const MQTT = ({Connected}) => {
  var client  = mqtt.connect(mqttBroker, mqttConnectOptions);
  client.on('connect', function() {
    {Connected}
  }
  return <div>...</div>;
}
```

sendAction:

```
export function sendAction(action) {
  return {
    type: action
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake and forgot parentheses in {Connected()}.
Child should look like this:

```
const MQTT = ({Connected}) => {
  var client  = mqtt.connect(mqttBroker, mqttConnectOptions);
  client.on('connect', function() {
    {Connected()}
  }
  return <div>...</div>;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the original question, do not use answers to provide updates, or if this the actual answer mark it as such by accepting it.

Comment: @hardillb You could also vote to close it, because this seems like a typo question.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't just call the `Connected` function you're passing down as a prop?

```
const MQTT = ({Connected}) => {
  var client  = mqtt.connect(mqttBroker, mqttConnectOptions);
  client.on('connect', function() {
    this.props.Connected()
    return <div>...</div>;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: That would return "TypeError: this.props is undefined", since I used {Connected} as a shortcut. However, I figured it out thanks to you. I forgot to include parentheses, so it was actually supposed to be {Connected()}, not {Connected}. Thank you!

Comment: Nice! What does the correct code look like?

Comment: I just answered it now, I just forgot parentheses in my function. Thank you for your help!